# How can I forward fill until a certain point and leave the rest as NANS in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe with daily values between a couple of months like this:

```
London 2000-01-01  5
London 2000-01-02  nan
London 2000-01-03  nan
..
London 2000-01-31  nan
London 2000-02-01  3
London 2000-02-02  nan
London 2000-02-01  nan
...
London 2000-02-31  nan
London 2000-03-01  nan
London 2000-01-01  nan
..
```

so for the first two months, there is a value on the first of the month, I want to forward fill that first of the month value to the whole months value but if I just use fillna with method = ffill, the third month will also be filled with the second months value. So I want it to be like this:

```
London 2000-01-01  5
London 2000-01-02  5
London 2000-01-03  5
..
London 2000-01-31  5
London 2000-02-01  3
London 2000-02-02  3
London 2000-02-01  3
...
London 2000-02-31  3
London 2000-03-01  nan
London 2000-01-01  nan
..
```

Is there a way to forward fill only the month ahead? my startdate and enddate will be variable so for example I may have first of the month data for 2000-01 all the way up until 2000-10 but my overall dataframe may be between 2000-01 to 2000-12 so I will have two months i want with only NANS. I am having trouble because each month has a different endday so I am unsure how to set the right condition for it. The dates are in datetime format.

Comment: You could groupby the place (i.e. London) and the year-month and `ffill` within the groupby which will prevent spilling over to later months.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2005-01-01', freq='D'))
values_to_set = [{'value':3, 'from':'2000-01', 'to':'2000-05'}, 
                 {'value':5, 'from':'2000-06', 'to':'2000-09'}
                ]

for v in values_to_set:
    df.loc[v['from']:v['to'], 'value'] = v['value']
    
df.loc['2000-09-28':'2000-10-02']
```

Option 2:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2005-01-01', freq='D'))

df.loc['2000-02-01', 'value'] = 5
df.loc['2000-05-01', 'value'] = 6

df.loc['2000-10-01', 'value'] = -1  # set stop value

df.ffill(inplace=True)
df.replace(-1, np.nan, inplace=True)

df.loc['2000-09-28':'2000-10-02']
```

Option 3

This is a tricky solution, probably someone else will come with a better one.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('2000-01-01', '2005-01-01', freq='D'))

df.loc['2000-02-01', 'value'] = 5
df.loc['2000-05-01', 'value'] = 6

_mask_1 = ~df['value'].isna()  # filters non empty values
_mask_2 = (df.index.day==1)  # filters 1st of each month

df.loc[_mask_1,'tmp'] = -1  # marks non empty values on a temporal column

df.loc[_mask_1|_mask_2, 'tmp'] =   df['tmp'][_mask_1|_mask_2].shift(1) # moves temp values one month ahead

_mask_3 = df['tmp'] == -1  # filters next month non empty
df.loc[_mask_3, 'value'] = -1   # set stop value on 'value' column
df.drop(columns='tmp', inplace=True)  # drops temporal column

# shows the stop mark for march
print(df['2000-02-28':'2000-03-02'])

# perform the forward filling

df.ffill(inplace=True)
df.replace(-1, np.nan, inplace=True)

print(df.loc['2000-02-28':'2000-03-02'])

print(df.loc['2000-05-28':'2000-06-02'])
```

Comment: I think the set stop value logic is exactly what im looking for thank you. Is there a way to do do 2000-05-01 + 1 month as a variable? so I would have in this instance Startdate = 2000-02-01 and enddate 2000-05-01, I would want your 6th line of code to be something like   df.loc['2000-05-01'+1 month, 'value'] = -1  # set stop value then I would continue with what you have done.

Comment: @Jason_Leto, what do you want to achieve with df.loc['2000-05-01'+1 month, 'value'] = -1? do you want to set two or more stop values before ffill?

Comment: Because my stop value will always be one month away from my last actual value. and I would want NANS between 2000-06-01 to 2000-10-01 so it would be enddate=2000-05-01 and then I would want something like enddate + pd.DateOffset(months=1) which I believe should work.

Comment: @Jason_Leto, added option 3, is very tricky though, probably someone will can find something cleaner